# XCode 6.2 bug on Master/Detail project template?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, simulator, master-detail, xcode-6.2

**This happens also on a blank Master/Detail project when using XCode 6.2 beta.**

In other words: it works on the simulator but gives me the error below when I run it on an iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1 installed (I don't have any other device to test it on).

Below is what I get adding the **exception breakpoint**.

[image]

I found the [following previous Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504305/universal-master-detail-application-with-core-data-and-tab-controller-for-iphone) but it does not seem to happen in the same case as mine. **Why would it work on the simulator?**

**Is this an XCode 6.2 bug? Can anyone reproduce it?**

Comment: Include the call stack and someone will be able to describe how you can figure out which line triggers it.

Comment: `topViewController` is a method of `UINavigationController`. Obviously your `MasterViewController` isn't a navigation controller.

Comment: To learn to debug, see: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: I remember that the simulator is rather good-natured about this errors.

Comment: I added the full stack.. however I am unable to understand which class and line of code is triggering this exception as I can't see more info other than the above and the image I added

Comment: Add an `Exception Breakpoint` for `Objective-C` (link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)and then post the code where your app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is because you are trying to use a `UISplitViewController` on an `iPhone` with `iOS 7`.  `UISplitViewController` was only available on the `iPhone` from `iOS 8+`. Prior to `iOS 8`, `UISplitViewController` was only available in the `iPad`.

Answer (score 0):

An important difference between the simulator and a device is that the simulator isn't case-sensitive when loading resources. Devices are. So it's possible a nib or other resource loads fine on the simulator but isn't found on the device because of a capitalization typo.

Comment: the weird thing is that this is on a blank project.. do u have XCode 6.2? Can u try running a blank master/detail test project on a real device? I got an iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1